# MongoDb script : Cannot compare two types correctly

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a mongoDB script.

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/metaiot");
var numbers = db.trips.find({trips :{$elemMatch : {"tripON":false}}});
numbers.forEach(function(setter)
    { for(var index in setter.trips){

        if(setter.trips[index]._id === ObjectId("562056e938396d1e248bbeee"))
            print("Yes");
    }
});
```

Now in my db I have a ObjectID.

```
ObjectId("56204f4a98114b0b23e7f833")
ObjectId("56204fbc8330653d23af74ef")
ObjectId("56205000190f575b238c8bb1")
ObjectId("562056e938396d1e248bbeee")
```

Here is output of one of the print statements. So it exists. But somehow `===` operator is not working. Why?? What is the possible workaround?

Comment: Duplicate? I disagree. The reason the code in both questions fail is the same, but goals for the solution are different. The referenced question wants a solution that avoids explicit object string conversion: ```.equals()``` is perfect for that. This question already has a string for comparison and ```.equals()``` would be clumsy here. ANSWER: In javascript, ```===``` is an identify operator for objects: an existing object can never ```===``` a new Object. Instead, use implicit string conversion for _id and the equality operator  ```if(setter.trips[index]._id == "562056e938396d1e248bbeee")```

Comment: Vote up for the information about Implicit string conversion for the _id field and why not to use === .